# git - how to create new remote branch and move some existing branches there?

Tags: git

On my remote branch there is a `feature` directory where all the features we are currently working sit. Some are actively been worked on, some have seen changes for a while.

We want to move the branches that have not been worked on to an `archive` directory so we keep the `feature` directory only with the active development and store the work of the inactive branches until a time where they can be revived and re-worked on.

How can I do that?

Comment: Why do you want to "archive branches"? A branch is just a commit id with a name.

Comment: The idea is that the feature directory should only contain active work. The archived branches are work we don't want to bin and that will be revisited at a later time.

Comment: Perhaps you should create a new repo like `origin` to store all your feature directory changes.

Comment: So I would have a repo `origin/feature` and `archive/feature`. That works. How do I move a branch from `origin/feature` to `archive/feature`?

Comment: check out my answer and see if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm getting what you're asking for, then you should create a new remote for your feature changes and keep the original one for archive (or vice-versa)

```
git remote add feature <remote_repo_address>

git push -f feature <branch_name> # do it will all the `feature` branches.

# origin should contain deprecated/archived branches in this case.
```

If you want to keep `origin` instead for new features, then do the reverse and all push all the branches to new remote and delete the same from the `origin`.